# Why normalsize doesn't work in subcaption?

Tags: tables, xetex, subcaption

Why `font=normalsize` doesn't work in subcaption? Example:

```
\documentclass{extreport}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Main caption}
  \begin{subtable}[t]{\linewidth}
    \centering
    \captionsetup{font=normalsize}
    \caption*{Subcaption}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
      \hline
      0           & 0          \\ \hline
      -1          & 1          \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
  \end{subtable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: subcaption example]

Comment: To me it seems to work. Why do you say it doesn't?

Comment: Main caption = 10pt, subcaption = 9pt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard setup for `subcaption` is `size=smaller`, which overrides the meaning of `\normalsize`.

Use `size=normal`. But you probably want a global setup.

```latex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \captionsetup{justification=raggedleft, singlelinecheck=false}
  \caption{Main caption}
  \begin{subtable}[t]{\linewidth}
    \centering
    \captionsetup{justification=centering,size=normal}
    \caption*{Subcaption}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
      \hline
      0           & 0          \\ \hline
      -1          & 1          \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
  \end{subtable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]